# How to cache the entire directory (platformio dependencies) in bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: esp8266, bitbucket-pipelines, platformio

I am running a CI pipeline to build firmware for ESP8266 using plaitformio and bitbucket pipelines, my code builds successfully and now I want to cache the directory that contains the platformio libraries (.piolibdeps). Here are the contains of my platform.ini file.

```
[env:nodemcuv2]
platform = espressif8266
board = nodemcuv2
framework = arduino
upload_port = 192.168.1.108

lib_deps =
    ESPAsyncTCP@1.1.0
    OneWire
    Time
    FauxmoESP
    Blynk
    DallasTemperature
    ArduinoJson
    Adafruit NeoPixel
```

How to cache this directory in BitBucket pipelines? Please see below the contents of bitbucket-pipelines.yml file, with this it is not caching the defined directory, what's wrong here?

```
image: eclipse/platformio

pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
    - step: 
        name: Build Project
        caches: # caches the depende
          - directories
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - pio ci --project-conf=./Code/UrbanAquarium.Firmware/platformio.ini ./Code/UrbanAquarium.Firmware/src
          - pwd
definitions:
  caches:
    directories: ./Code/UrbanAquarium.Firmware/.piolibdeps
```

And here my folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in case you're still looking for an answer - I think you got it almost right, but probably need to specify a custom `--build-dir` (so that you can specify the same path for your cache) as well as `--keep-build-dir` (see https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/userguide/cmd_ci.html). Also, I'm not sure why you specified a `./Code/UrbanAquarium.Firmware/` prefix.

That said, I've tried the above and it became quickly ugly - for now I'll only cache `~/.platformio`, as well as the default `pip` cache:

```
image: python:2.7.16

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - pip
          - pio
        script:
          - pip install -U platformio
          - platformio update
          - platformio ci src/ --project-conf=platformio.ini

definitions:
  caches:
    pio: ~/.platformio
```

Comment: Great job with this example pipeline